# UnsupportedEncodingException

Tags: java, spring

I am working on restful api of spring and i am send parameters from my browser to my server(localhost). My server will call the link in world wide web and get the result. Here I am getting the exception. 
Following is the original link i have to get the 
https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=science%5bjournal%5d+AND+breast+cancer+AND+2008%5bpdat%5d

THIS IS MY link i call in browser

http://localhost:8080/search?db=pubmed&term=science[journal]+AND+breast+cancer+AND+2008[pdat]

Please help me out.

```
package com.ncbi.team.utils;


            import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    enter code here

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

@Service
public class SearchReq {


    public String browseURL(List <String> param ) 

throwsUnsupportedEncodingExce

ption{

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String masterURL = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi";

    System.out.println(param);
    sb.append(masterURL);

 for(int i=0;i<param.size();i++)    
 {  

    if(i==0){
        sb.append("?");
        sb.append(param.get(0));
    }

    else{
        sb.append("&"+param.get(i));

    }
 }
System.out.println("URL Is :"+sb.toString());
Client c = Client.create(); 

String url=URLEncoder.encode(sb.toString(),"UTF-8");
```

// WebResource resource = c.resource(URLEncoder.encode(sb.toString(),"UTF-8"));
     WebResource resource = c.resource(url);

```
//@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
//WebResource resource = c.resource(sb.toString());

ClientResponse resp = resource.accept("text/html").get(ClientResponse.class);

String xml= null;

if(resp.getStatus() == 200){
    xml = resp.getEntity(String.class);

}

 return xml;
}
```

}

Comment: Please note that even resource = c.resource(url); is part of the code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take a moment to review this [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask the best possible question, and thus get the best possible answer.